# Loop for display help command

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, discord.js

Actually, i try to create a bot with discord.js and i try to do a help command.

i don't understand why my loop do this (i know it's not a good way for this)

```js
let i = 0;
const embed = new RichEmbed();

if (args.length < 1) {
  embed.setColor('#5B4DCA');
  while (i < list_groups.length) {
    let x = 0;
    embed.setTitle(`${list_groups[i]}`)
    while (x < groups.length) {
      if (groups[x] === list_groups[i]) {
        embed.addField('test1', 'test2')
      }
      x++;
    }
    message.channel.send(embed)
    i++;
  }
}
```

"Modérations" is supposed to display one command, "level & rank" too, "Outils" 4 command and "Sondage" too

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGWI4.png)

Comment: To answer your question, need to understand the structure of list_groups

Comment: "list_groups" contain a list of all groups and it's set by this ( n.b : bloc of code)
and "groups" it's a attribut of command, look like a category

`
if (!list_groups.includes(f.help.groups)) {
            list_groups.push(f.help.groups)
        }
`

Comment: Show pls one of your exports.help block.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8KmQ46w9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you solutuion its not right way. If you will have more then 10 groups bot will spam commands list. The 1 way to do it its display all categories list if `args.length===0`, if args  !==0 you try to find all commands in this category. To discord embed you can add only 18 fields, so if you have more then 18 command in categroy you will get api error. So you need spliced commands to pages.

This code will display all categories if args.length === 0, or command groups not fined. 
If group fined bot send embed message with command in group (max 10), and react message if pages more then 1, so user can change page with reaction.

```js
   const {Discord,RichEmbed} = require('discord.js');
    const {prefix,token,classic_roles} = require('../config.json');
    const logs = require('../logs/logs');

    module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
        if(args.length === 0) {
            //Show user all allowed groups commands 
            let commandCategories = bot.commands.map(command => `!help ${command.help.groups}`).filter(onlyUnique).join('\n') //find all categories and get onlyUnique
            let helpMessage = `**The list of command groups:**\n\n ${commandCategories}`
            let Embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarUrl)
                .setDescription(helpMessage)
                .setColor('#e0c40b')
            message.channel.send(Embed)
        } else {
            //try find required group 
            let commandsInCategory = bot.commands.filter(command => command.help.groups === args.join(' ').toLowerCase())
            if(commandsInCategory.size === 0) {
                // if no group find, then display user list of groups 
                let commandCategories = bot.commands.map(command => `!help ${command.help.groups}`).filter(onlyUnique).join('\n')
                let helpMessage = `**For get command list use**\n\n ${commandCategories}`
                        let Embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarUrl)
                .setDescription(helpMessage)
                .setColor('#e0c40b')
            message.channel.send(Embed)
                return
            }
            let counter = 0
            let allCommands = []
            commandsInCategory.map(command => {
                allCommands.push({
                    name: command.help.name,
                    description: command.help.description
                })
            })

            allCommands = generateHelpArray(allCommands)
            //for better display, we will display only 10 in page
            let Embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                Embed.setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarUrl)
                Embed.setDescription(`The list command of group : **${args.join(' ')}**`)
                allCommands[counter].map(command => {
                    Embed.addField(`**${command.name}**`,`${command.description}`,false)
                })
                Embed.setColor('#E8DB0E')
                Embed.setFooter(`Page ${counter+1} of ${allCommands.length}`)
                message.channel.send(Embed).then(msg => {
                    if(allCommands.length < 2) return
                    // To change page we will use react emoji 
                    msg.react(`◀️`).then(() => msg.react('▶️'))
                    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                        return [`◀️`, '▶️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
                    };
                    const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(filter, { max:50, time: 60000 });
                    collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
                        if (reaction.emoji.name === `◀️`) {
                            //Change counter, remove user reaction and call change embed function 
                            reaction.remove(message.author.id)
                            counter-=1
                            if(counter < 0) counter = 0
                            editEmbed(message, msg, counter, args.join(' '), allCommands)
                        } else if (reaction.emoji.name === `▶️`) {
                            //Change counter, remove user reaction and call change embed function 
                            reaction.remove(message.author.id)
                            counter+=1
                            if(counter >= allCommands.length) counter = allCommands.length -1
                            editEmbed(message, msg, counter, args.join(' '), allCommands)
                        }
                   });
                   collector.on('end', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
                    msg.clearReactions()
                   })
                })

        }
    }

    module.exports.help = {
        name: "help",
        description: "Vous permet d'obtenir toutes les commandes accessibles pour vos rôles.",
        access: "Public",
        groups: "Outils"
    }




    const onlyUnique = (value, index, self) => { 
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    }


    const editEmbed = (message, msg, counter, category, allCommands) => {
        let Embed  = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            Embed.setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
            Embed.setDescription(`The list command of group : **${category}**`)
            Embed.setColor('#E8DB0E')
            allCommands[counter].map(command => {
                Embed.addField(`**${command.name}**`,`${command.description}`,false)
            })
            Embed.setFooter(`Page ${counter+1} of ${allCommands.length}`)
            msg.edit(Embed)
    }

    const generateHelpArray = (arr) => {
        let newArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=10) {
        newArray.push(arr.slice(i,i+10))
        }
        return newArray
    }
```

Comment: Thx for the code, actually with this code, no command is display but i will recode this with help of your code, i have a better comprehension of embed.

And sorry for my English, I'm really bad with this language

Comment: Thats display command name, but you can modife list of Array args, just add it to 
             allCommands.push({
                    name: command.help.name,
                    description: command.help.description,
                })